# How to Call Class on page load in Html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have jquery with class= modal i want to call that class when page load how to do using javascript or php

Comment: What do you mean _call that class_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*Code Here/* });
```

(which is equivalent to `$(function(){ /*Code Here/* });`) 
to execute the code when the DOM is ready, or you can use

```
$(document).load(function(){ /*Code Here/* });
```

to execute the code once all sub-elements have also been loaded, i.e. images.

Answer (score 0):

To do something after page has been loaded, use jQuery like:

```
$(function(){
   // code that should run after page has finished loading
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code just before the `</body>` tag, like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
        $('.modal')....
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: wont work if jQuery has not finished loading....

Comment: if the jquery library is called before this code, it will be already loaded, as browsers load all JavaScript in the same order it's placed on the code